# QnA Maker's metadata

Tags: azure, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, azure-qna-maker

So, I am pretty new when it comer to the development os AI's, principally with Microsoft Azure's tools. I was using Azure's QnA Maker Preview to develop a FAQ bot. But just today, Microsoft released a huuuuge update, making this servisse much more powerful, adding, together with other new features, the concept of **metadata**. I understood that it is supposed to make your system more powerful, fast and intelligent, but I didn't understand how it should be used and what exactly it does. Can anyone help me to understand this new tool? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use metadata as a key value pair collection to differentiate questions. For example ‘categories’. You can then use these when you query generateAnswer endpoint to filter your matches. Check out the v3 generateAnswer api documentation for an example post payload.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Meta Data in Generate Answer Api to get answer from specific data source

e.g
json { "question": "How are you", "top": 6, "strictFilters": [ { "name": "category", "value": "api" }], "userId": "sd53lsY=" }

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details at links -
[QnAMaker - Add Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/edit-knowledge-base#add-metadata)
and
[QnAMaker - V3.0](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/597029932bcd590e74b648fb/operations/597037798a8bb5031800bf5b)

Comment: I know how to add the metadata, but I didn't get how it works, even after seeing these links...